# How to check the missing pieces of a given set?

Tags: storage, organisation, alternate-model

I have a collection of LEGO sets, from which only the B model is assembled and the remaining pieces have been lost.

What is the easiest way to figure out which pieces are missing from these sets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Compare Sets](https://rebrickable.com/sets/compare/slow/) function on [Rebrickable](https://rebrickable.com/) for that (if the B model is an official model or a MOC on Rebrickable).

Here an [example for both official models from the 42069 set](https://rebrickable.com/sets/compare/slow/?1-set=42069-1&1-inv=19190&1-user_list=&2-set=42069-1-b1&2-inv=24927&2-user_list=).